# How to fit single speed tensioner onto bike?

Tags: single-speed

I have recently replaced my old Gusset Bachelor SS tensioner for a new Gusset sprung tensioner with a jockey wheel (https://www.gussetcomponents.com/shop/chains-and-chain-devices/squire-ss-tensioner/). However I can't seem to tighten the bolt into the mount (the hole next to the drop out, where the tensioner attaches). I'll add some pictures to make it clearer. When I tighten the bolt with a hex key it just keeps spinning and will be loose, however if I take the spring mechanism out of the housing the bolts tightens just fine, so the spring is blocking part of the bolt to be tightened maybe. I'd appreciate any advice.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Question on the side: why do you need a tensioner? Shorten the chain to 1-1.5cm slack, use a re-usable master link and leave the tensioner away.

Comment: Because the drop outs are vertical, unlike horizontal drop outs you can't adjust the wheel position to create more tension/slack in the chain

Comment: Check the threads on the derailleur hanger and the bolt to be undamaged. Check if the spring can be rotated to be put in a better position relative to the hanger or the arm.

Comment: Did you have the chain on when installing the tensioner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it a push up or pull down spring? As far as I know, the chain can be put in tension both ways, but a specific tensioner will work only in one direction (either pulling up or pushing down, therefore the chain should run above or below the jockey wheel.

Emergency fix: run the chain above the jockey wheel and zip tie the tensioner to the frame.

Comment: Good idea - pushing up at the bottom would give more chain/tooth engagement on the sprocket and chainring.